# Source for colored Wratten filters?

Tags: filters, color

I need 13 different Wratten gelatin filters to use in some research in anatomy and I need a specific spectrum of light filters. I need #'s 3, 9, 15, 16, 21, 24, 25, 29, 44, 53, 58, 98, and 31 or 32. They don't have to be Kodak, nor do they need to be glass.

I don't have a lot of money to spend so I need the best quality for the least amount. Does anyone have any sources that I can contact to try to procure these filters. Thanks for your help and input, I know this is a rather unusual request!

Comment: It would help if A) you let us know where in the world you were and B) why Google hasn't helped you.

Comment: The last time I looked, there were a lot on Ebay.

Answer (score 1):

One source of inexpensive filters would be a store with used photography items - some of these filters were used in traditional B&W and color photography and you may find some of them for very little money. Filters with the same spectra as Wratten filters were available from other manufacturers with different naming. It might be useful to google it and find equivalent filter names for other brands before visiting such store.

I would also suggest looking at web sites of companies like Rosco and Lee. [Quick look at the rosco web site here](http://www.rosco.com/filters/roscolux.cfm), [here](http://www.rosco.com/filters/ecolour.cfm?DisplayType=36) and elsewhere suggests that you will be able to source many of the filters from them, but they are intended for modification of light (in front of a flash, for example), not to be mounted in front of a lens. Lee makes a large selection of camera filters, their polyester filters are inexpensive, too.